# The Register equivalent of wp_signon is what

Tags: php, wordpress

What is the registration equivalent on wordpress of WP_SIGNON

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon

It is not WP_REGISTER annoyingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for `wp_insert_user()` located in `wp-includes/user.php`.

Answer (score 2):

A quick browsing of the [**function reference**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) returned [**wp_create_user()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user)

> The wp_create_user function allows you to insert a new user into the
>   WordPress database by parsing 3 (three) parameters through to the
>   function itself.

**Usage:**

```
 <?php wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email ); ?>
```

And as already said by @Vladimir, [**wp_insert_user()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user), which:

> Insert a user into the database. Can update a current user or insert a
>   new user based on whether the user's ID is present.

**Usage:**

```
<?php wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ?>
```